# What was Ahmet locked up for?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, midnight-express

The guy "Ahmet" in Midnight Express, who was an Oxford educated character (?), spoke good English and had a degree in philosophy was locked up underground in a Turkish jail, where they meet. Is it known what Ahmet was there for, which crime he was convicted for or is it not said?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Midnight-Express.html):-

```
      AHMET
 ...They put me here. They say I 
 raped a little boy. I have been 
 here very long time. They will 
 never let me go.
```